# Filter in a Listbox with a lambda stream C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well I'd like to filter in a ListBox in C#. I have an Input Field and every time the text in the textbox is changed it should filter.

I fill my listbox with this lambda stream:

```
db.Suppliers.Select(x => x.CompanyName).OrderBy(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x => listBox.Items.Add(x));
```

Then I have a method `textBox_TextChanged`

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) == false)
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var obj in list)
            {
                if (obj.ToString().StartsWith(textBox.Text))
                {
                    listBox.Items.Add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If it is possible I'd like to make a lambda stream to filter. The filtered Items should be displayed then in the listbox where all the stuff is listed before filtering.

This means if I input f.e. an G into the textBox then there should only showed string which starts with G

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) == false)
    {
        listBox.Items = list.Select(p => p.ToString()).Where(p => p.StartsWith(textBox.Text)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just got it I was absolutely brain AFK. ;)

Comment: @yen, 
I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
 listBox.Items = list.Select(x => x.CompanyName)
                     .Where(c=> c.StartsWith(textBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                     .OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
}
```